# text selection and highlighting in android

Tags: android

In my project i am able to render pdf.Now  i want to search the words in the pdf and want to highlight .can anybody suggest for me.
 thanking you in advance..

Comment: Are you rendering pdf on Android? What are you using to do this?

Comment: yes i am rendering pdf in android only using jni.